# Calculus Limits

Tags: calculus, limits

so far I have done:

$=\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac {(V(t+h)-V(t))} h$

$=\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac {(V(10+h)-V(10))} h$

$=\lim\limits_{h \to 0} 20(1-(100/(100+(10+h))-(20(1-(100/(100+(10^2)))))$

so I'm not sure how to finish and sorry I didn't know how to convert to the other form looking like the equation

Comment: simplify the fraction.  You should be able to cancel a factor of $h$ from the numerator and denominator.

Comment: Hey matthew thats whats i'm trying to do but i keep getting the wrong answer, would you be able to show me? thanks

Comment: Looks like you have an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac {dv}{dt}  = $$\lim_\limits {h\to 0} \dfrac {20(1 - \frac {100}{100+(t+h)^2}) - 20(1 - \frac {100}{100+t^2})}{h}\\
\lim_\limits {h\to 0}20 \dfrac {1 - \frac {100}{100+(t+h)^2} -1 + \frac {100}{100+t^2}}{h}\\
\lim_\limits {h\to 0}20 \dfrac {-\frac {100}{100+(t+h)^2} + \frac {100}{100+t^2}}{h}\\
\lim_\limits {h\to 0}2000 \dfrac {-\frac {1}{100+(t+h)^2} + \frac {1}{100+t^2}}{h}\\
\lim_\limits {h\to 0}2000 \dfrac {-(100+t^2)+(100+(t+h)^2)}{h(100+(t+h)^2)(100+t^2)}\\
\lim_\limits {h\to 0}2000 \dfrac {-100-t^2+100+t^2+2th +h^2)}{h(100+(t+h)^2)(100+t^2)}\\
\lim_\limits {h\to 0}2000 \dfrac {2th +h^2}{h(100+(t+h)^2)(100+t^2)}\\
\lim_\limits {h\to 0}2000 \dfrac {2t +h}{(100+(t+h)^2)(100+t^2)}\\
$

And let $h$ go to $0$

$\frac {dv}{dt} = 2000 \dfrac {2t }{(100+t^2)^2}$

and set $t=10$

Comment: Thank you so much Doug I was having problems simplifying the fraction, much appreciated!